# How to run .mp4 videos on firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, firefox, video, ffmpeg

When play mp4 videos on chrome it works fine.But same videos not playing on firefox. After some search I found this

> Firefox does not support .mp4 playback. Try conveting the video to .ogg format which is fast becoming a standard format for html 5 applications.

Now how I convert this to ogg for firefox.
My model code is

```
has_attached_file :videod, :styles => { 
  :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4' },
  :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
}, :processors => [:ffmpeg]
validates_attachment_size :videod, :less_than => 100.megabytes
    validates_attachment_presence :videod
    validates_attachment_content_type :videod, :content_type => /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
```

Comment: What OS and what version of Firefox do you have?

Comment: ubuntu and Mozilla Firefox 38.0

Comment: It should work. Do you have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed? For HTML5 you sould use `webm`. Guide for `ffmpeg` here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8 (there's also support for VP9 if you want)

Comment: Yes all ubuntu-restricted-extras installed are installed

Comment: [Firefox supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#MP4_H.264_(AAC_or_MP3)) `MP4` with `H/264` and `AAC` or `MP3`. Can you check your file with `ffprobe` and see what it says?

Comment: in the console `ffprobe movie.mp4`  where movie.mp4 is a file that doesn't work in Firefox.